# sorting and oncellfocusing is not working in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We used the V18.1 custom Ag-grid component for our entire application. However, the combination of onCellFocus and sorting is not working correctly. The issue arises from the mismatched DOM focus when selecting rows in the grids.

```
onCellFocused = (e) => {        
    if (e.rowIndex !== null) {
        const selectedData = this.gridChild.getSelectedRows();       
        let pin = 0;
        if(selectedData !== undefined) { 
            selectedData.map(row => {
                pin = row.pin;
            });
        }

        this.bindTechSpecLineItems(pin, e);

        if(e.column.getId() === 'expenseDate' || e.column.getId() === 'expenseDescription') {
            this.setState({ isReloadGrid : true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ isReloadGrid : false });
        }

        if(document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex) !== null) {
            if(document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).type === 'text') {                    
                document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).select();     
            } else if(document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).type === 'select-one') {
                if(e.forceBrowserFocus) 
                    document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).focus();
                else
                    document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).click();
            } else {                    
                document.getElementById(e.column.getId() + e.rowIndex).focus();                    
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

in the header column file

```
"rowSelection": 'multiple',         
        "pagination": false,
        "enableFilter": false,
        "enableSorting": true,          
        "searchable": false,
        "gridActions": true,
        "gridTitlePanel": false,
        "headerHeight":40,
```

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i re-edit my question daxelarne